# Boost serialization of derived object does not call derived serialize()

Tags: xml, templates, serialization, boost, boost-serialization

I have a template class `Field` that derives from `IField`. This makes it possible to add any specific `Field` like `Field<int>` and `Field<double>` to a `std::vector<IField>`. In the Model-class I'm serializing this vector. I can compile everything, but I'm not getting the desired output. Thank you for any help!

My abstract class:

```
class IField {
public:
    IField(){}
    virtual ~IField() {}

private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive&, const unsigned int) {}
};

BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(IField)
```

My template class:

```
template<typename T>
class Field: public IField {
public:

    Field(std::string name, T value) :
            mName(name), mValue(value) {
    }

    const std::string& getName() const {
        return mName;
    }

    void setName(const std::string& name) {
        mName = name;
    }

    T getValue() const {
        return mValue;
    }

    void setValue(T value) {
        mValue = value;
    }

private:

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& archive, const unsigned int) {
        archive & boost::serialization::make_nvp("IField", boost::serialization::base_object<IField>(*this));
        archive & boost::serialization::make_nvp("Name", mName);
        archive & boost::serialization::make_nvp("Value", mValue);
    }

    std::string mName;
    T mValue;
};
```

My customized vector-class `std::vector<IField>`:

```
class FieldSet: public std::vector<IField> {
public:
    FieldSet() :
            mSize(0) {
    }
    virtual ~FieldSet() {
    }

private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version) {
        if (Archive::is_loading::value) {
            this->clear();
            ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("Size", mSize);
            for (int i = 0; i < mSize; i++) {
                IField field;
                ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("Field", field);
                this->push_back(field);
            }
        } else {
            mSize = this->size();
            ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("Size", mSize);
            for (int i = 0; i < mSize; i++) {
                ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("Field", this->at(i));
            }
        }
    }

    int mSize; // You have to add vector size
};
```

My Model.h:

```
class Model {
public:
    Model();
    virtual ~Model(){}

private:
    FieldSet mFieldSet;

    // Fields
    Field<int> mTime;
    Field<double> mSpeed;
};
```

My Model.cpp:

```
Model::Model (): mTime("Time", 0), mSpeed("Speed", 0.0) {
    mFieldSet.push_back(mTime);
    mFieldSet.push_back(mSpeed);
}

void Model::store(std::string filename) {
    std::ofstream ofs(filename);
    boost::archive::xml_oarchive oa(ofs);
    oa << boost::serialization::make_nvp("FieldSet", mFieldSet);
}
```

I'm getting the folling XML-output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<!DOCTYPE boost_serialization>
<boost_serialization signature="serialization::archive" version="10">
    <FieldSet class_id="0" tracking_level="0" version="0">
        <Size>5</Size>
        <Field class_id="1" tracking_level="0" version="0"></Field>
        <Field></Field>
        <Field></Field>
    </FieldSet>
</boost_serialization>
```

But want to have the output as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<!DOCTYPE boost_serialization>
<boost_serialization signature="serialization::archive" version="10">
    <FieldSet class_id="0" tracking_level="0" version="0">
        <Size>5</Size>
        <Field class_id="1" tracking_level="0" version="0"></Field>
        <Field>
            <Name>Time</Name>
            <Value>0</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field>
            <Name>Speed</Name>
            <Value>0.0</Value>
        </Field>
    </FieldSet>
</boost_serialization>
```

Comment: Your `std::vector<IField>` holds `IField` objects by value, so any derived info gets sliced away. Since `IField` has no data members, you basically have a vector of empty objects. If you want to store polymorphic objects in a vector, you need to have a vector of pointers to base (ideally smart pointers). | Also your "abstract class" is not really abstract AFAICT.

Comment: @DanMašek Thank you so much!. You were right. It's working now :)